# Last item in listview doesn't scroll completely

Tags: android

I am using listview in my layout. But while scrolling down the last item in the list doesnt scroll and fit in the list. Even the focus is on the last item still there is some space to scroll. I have to press twice on the last item as down key to get it properly set on the list.
Could anyone help me on this?

```
Activity_Layout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="122px"
    android:layout_marginTop="67px"
    android:layout_marginRight="122px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="67px"
    android:background="@drawable/nno_bg">

        <TextView
            style="@style/dialogues_nownext_overview_header_title_text_style"
            android:layout_width="1556px"
            android:layout_height="50px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
            android:layout_marginTop="40px"
            android:text="@string/MAIN_TI_CHANNEL_OVERVIEW" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/DateTime"
            style="@style/dialogues_nownext_overview_header_sub_title_text_style"
            android:layout_width="1556px"
            android:layout_height="34px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50px"
            android:layout_marginTop="102px" />
        
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/nno_list_parent"
            android:layout_width="1618px"
            android:layout_height="620px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25px"
            android:layout_marginTop="180px" >
        
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/nno_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:scrollbarSize="2dp"
                android:focusable="true"
                android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
        </LinearLayout> 

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nno_close"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:layout_width="194px"
            android:layout_height="67px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1407px"
            android:layout_marginTop="840px"
            style="@style/button_style"
            android:text="@org.droidtv.ui.strings:string/MAIN_COLOUR_CLOSE" />
</RelativeLayout>

List_Row

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Row"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="80px"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/channelNameParent"
        android:layout_width="520px"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25px">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/channelName"
            android:layout_width="460px"
            android:layout_height="42px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>         

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nowevent"
        android:layout_width="540px"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="554px"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:focusable="false" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nowStartTime"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="42px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
            style="@style/dialogues_nownext_overview_header_sub_title_text_style"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nowEventName"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="42px"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            style="@style/dialogues_nownext_overview_header_sub_title_text_style"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
            
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/nextevent1"
        android:layout_width="540px"
        android:layout_height="80px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="1103px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nextStartTime"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="42px"
            style="@style/dialoguestitle_text_style"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nextEventName"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="42px"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:focusable="true"
            style="@style/dialoguessub_title_text_style"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

Could anyone please help?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp">
  
      //put your code here

     </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```